# Grails Spock Integration test mapping of class in configuration file

Tags: grails-2.0, spock

I wanted to know where is the mapping of integration test classes done in Grails. 
Actually I am trying to rename the default class to my application specific class, but when I am refactoring it then my test cases are not run.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem in a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You should more details to your question (build scripts, relevant parts of the configuration files, project structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append Spec to your class name.
For example your class name is People then your class name should be PeopleSpec.
Here Spec for Specification in Spock